# Trying to order state and city on custom fields using meta_query

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-query

I am trying to order custom fields by state and city. This is for a WordPress website and I am using ACF custom fields.

Find my unsuccessful meta_query below.

```
  $hotel = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type'           => 'hotel',
      'meta_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'AND',
   
          'country' => array(
            'meta_key' => 'hotel_address_country',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
          ),

          'city' => array(
            'meta_key' => 'hotel_address_city_state',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
          ),
        ),

        'orderby' => array(
          'country' => 'DESC',
          'city' => 'ASC',
        ),
      'numberposts' => -1,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'public'      => 'true',
      'posts_per_page' => '500',
   ) );
```

Comment: Does [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745334/how-to-order-by-multiple-meta-keys) help with your query to order by multiple meta keys?

Comment: Thanks, I can do that one. I get stuck when I try to order two meta_values using a meta_query.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to test. But I got this feedback and think it will work in case anyone else is looking for the solution...

$hotel = new WP_Query(
array(
'post_type'      => 'hotel',
'numberposts'    => -1,
'meta_query'     => array(
'relation'       => 'AND',
'country_clause' => array(
'key'     => 'hotel_country',
'compare' => 'EXISTS',
),
'city_clause'    => array(
'key'     => 'hotel_city',
'compare' => 'EXISTS',
),

```
    ),
    'orderby'        => array(
        'country_clause' => 'ASC',
        'city_clause'    => 'ASC',
    ),

    // 'post_status' => 'publish',
    // 'public' => 'true',
    'posts_per_page' => '500',
)
```

);